# Почему добавляются непонятные символы в БД при вводе русских букв (кириллицы) в phpMyAdmin?

Tags: кодировка, utf-8, кириллица

На странице, в которой ввожу данные, кодировка текста "< meta charset="utf-8>". Ввел строку "Главная"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вывод на другой странице выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В БД кодировка - utf8_general_ci, а запись этих строк выглядит вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скрипт, который пишет в БД, не установлена кодировка обмена с mysql. В итоге скрипт пишет в БД в кодировке по умолчанию (скорее всего Latin). Поскольку и читает он в этой же кодировке, то на сайте все отображается как надо, а вот в phpMyAdmin, настроенном на utf8, вы видите "кракозябры".

В скрипте, после соединения с БД надо выполнить запрос

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

чтобы установить нужную кодировку обмена с БД

Comment: Теперь на странице, в которой загружается строка из БД "????????", а в БД все правильно.

Comment: Простите за сумбур), разобрался.